# C++ "undefined reference to" error

Tags: c++, file, compilation, header

First of all don't panic. It is a very simple program.
I get this error when compiling Main.cpp with "g++ -Wall -pedantic Main.cpp"
Here are all my Files. What causes the undefined reference to error?

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BMWLogo.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include "IVehicle.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "BMW.h"

int main() {
    BMW* bmw = new BMW();
    Car* car = bmw;
    std::cout << car->getName() << std::endl;
}
```

**IVehicle.h**

```
class IVehicle {
    public:
        IVehicle();
        virtual std::string getName();
        virtual float getCurrentSpeed();
};
```

**IVehicle.cpp**

```
#include "IVehicle.h"

IVehicle::IVehicle() {

}
virtual std::string IVehicle::getName() {

}
virtual float IVehicle::getCurrentSpeed() {

}
```

**Car.h**

```
class Car : public IVehicle {

    private:
        std::string name;
        float currentSpeed;
        Engine* engine;
    public:
        Car(std::string name);

        void setCurrentSpeed(float currentSpeed);

        float getCurrentSpeed();

        std::string getName();

};
```

**Car.cpp**

```
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
    engine = new Engine();
}

void Car::setCurrentSpeed(float currentSpeed) {
    this->currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
}

float Car::getCurrentSpeed() {
    return currentSpeed;
}

std::string Car::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

**BMW.h**

```
class BMW : public Car {
    private: 
        BMWLogo* bmwLogo;
    public:
        BMW();
};
```

**BMW.cpp**

```
#include "BMW.h"

BMW::BMW()
: Car("BMW") {
    bmwLogo = new BMWLogo();
}
```

**Engine.h**

```
class Engine {

    Engine();

};
```

**Engine.cpp**

```
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine() {

}
```

**BMWLogo.h**

```
class BMWLogo {

    BMWLogo();

};
```

**BMWLogo.cpp**

```
#include "BMWLogo.h"

BMLogo::BMWLogo() {

}
```

Comment: "First of all don't panic" hehe

Comment: Undefined reference to *what*? Show us the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: undefined reference to 'BMW::BMW()'

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the definition of the `IVehicle` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I think IVehicle.h needs to be referenced in Car.h

`#include "IVehicle.h"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a different problem to what you asked but you might want to note it for latter, see your code:

```
Car::Car(std::string name) {
    name = name;
    engine = new Engine();
}
```

You might want to change the parameter name so that it isn't hiding the class instance of name. Try:

```
Car::Car(std::string p_name) {
    name = p_name;
    engine = new Engine();
}
```

Comment: or at least just type `this->name = name`